# Automatically push to a remote branch with a different name?

Tags: git

I have a local branch named `future-db` which is tracking the remote branch `wip/future-db`. This part works fine:

```
$ git push -u upstream future-db:wip/future-db
Branch future-db set up to track remote branch wip/future-db from upstream.
Everything up-to-date

$ git status  
On branch future-db  
Your branch is up-to-date with 'upstream/wip/future-db'.
```

When doing `git push` I'd now expect it to push to `wip/future-db`. However, it creates a new remote branch named `future-db`.

Comment: For all those who got confused like me , he did `git push` after  `git push -u upstream future-db:wip/future-db` . I thought the latter command created new branch.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of the `push.default` config option being set to something different than `upstream` (usually the default. i.e. `simple` or `matching`).

Changing it using `git config push.default upstream` solves the problem and causes `git push` to push to the proper branch.

Comment: `matching` was the default behavior prior to Git version 2.0. With 2.0, `simple` is now the default.